# Adding CSS to <a> Tag Not Working

Tags: css, button, youtube

I tried adding CSS to a button, but it just outputs as a plain hyperlink.
Do I need to use a `<button>` tag instead?

```
<a href="example.com" style=".button { /*Tons of correctly written, irrelevant CSS */ }">text</a>
```

Comment: missing `=` on the style tag

Comment: I suggest you use use quote marks. eg `<a href = "place" id = "something" class="thisClass" style="mystyle:groovy;" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its should be like this -

```html
<a title="Subcribe now" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/danielspringermusic?sub_confirmation=1" style="text-decoration:none; text-align:center; 
 padding:6px 12px; 
 border:solid 3px #cc6300; 
 -webkit-border-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius:8px; 
 border-radius: 8px; 
 font:17px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 color:#000000; 
 background:#c4302b; 
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  

 text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #bababa; 
 filter: dropshadow(color=#bababa, offx=0, offy=0); }.button:hover{
 padding:6px 12px; 
 border:solid 3px #cc6300; 
 -webkit-border-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius:8px; 
 border-radius: 8px; 
 font:17px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 color:#000000; 
 background-color:#c42b3d; 
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c42b3d 0%, #2ba0c4 100%); 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c42b3d 0%, #2ba0c4 100%); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c42b3d 0%, #2ba0c4 100%); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c42b3d 0% ,#2ba0c4 100%); 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2ba0c4', endColorstr='#2ba0c4',GradientType=0 ); 
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #c42b3d 0% ,#2ba0c4 100%);   
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  

 text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #bababa; 
 filter: dropshadow(color=#bababa, offx=0, offy=0);}.button:active{
 padding:6px 12px; 
 border:solid 3px #cc6300; 
 -webkit-border-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius:8px; 
 border-radius: 8px; 
 font:17px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 color:#000000; 
 background:#c4302b; 
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  

 text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #bababa; 
 filter: dropshadow(color=#bababa, offx=0, offy=0);}">SubscribE</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Maddy you are correct! So besides the "=", I had to remove the ".button"? Is that it?

Comment: I could be wrong, but this looks broken to me. There's the closing `}` for the original `.button {`, and there's also `.button:hover {...}` and `.button:active {...}` which I'm 99.99% certain is illegal in the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a "="-sign at:

```
style="text-decoration:none; ...
```

And I strongly suggest that you outsource the css in a seperate stylesheet

Comment: I think you need to test your suggestion out as even with the `=` it will not work.

Comment: it doesn't work because he defines a `.button` class inside the style-tag of the button itself which is why I suggested to outsource the css in a seperate stylesheet because than it'd work

Comment: Exactly, but until your edit you were suggesting that they continue using `style=".button`. Your answer is better now you have corrected it!

Comment: You're right, I should have specified why I suggest to outsource it. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If use inline element sample :

```
<a href="#" style="border:1px"
```

Not use : `<a href="#" style=".button{border:1px}"`